# how do i interpret this Facebook login review rejection?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I submitted my application for Facebook's login review and was rejected. This is in part because I didn't actually show the action that required the permissions I'm requesting because I thought I needed to request them first. In their feedback, they mention the following:

> Any account listed in the Roles tab in your App Dashboard, such as 
>   admins, developers and testers, can access all permissions and generate > a user or page access token. You can use any of these accounts to test
>   your app...”

Despite what they’ve said, when I hit the api endpoint, I get an authorization error saying that I still need those permissions despite being logged in as an admin. As the statement above says, I should have all permissions but I do not.

I'm trying to get the page access token for a specific page so the endpoint is /2.9/{a page-id i found on my page}?fields=access_token.
The error message from hitting that endpoint includes

> Unsupported get request. Object with ID '{a page-id i found on my page}' does not 
>   exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support 
>   this operation.

The id definitely exists, I *should* have the permissions as an admin, and a simple read is supported. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of course your app still needs to get the permission from the user. What they told is just that your app _can_ ask any user that has a role in the app for those permissions, before you get them reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

As per your post, it seems that you don't have a developer permission. Follow the below links, it worked for me, hope it does the same for your.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-first-facebook-app--net-471

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Facebook-Application

https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/how-to-make-a-facebook-app-for-your-site